# Hatcher Exercise 3.2.11

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having trouble doing exercise 3.2.11 at page 231 of Hatcher. It states:

> Using cup products, show that every map $S^{k+l}\to S^k\times S^l$ induces the trivial homomorphism $H_{k+l}(S^{k+l})\to H_{k+l}(S^k\times S^l)$.

I don't know how to use the cup product in order to do this kind of computations. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $H^*(S^n)$ is an exterior algebra $\Lambda(x,n)$ with $x$ in degree $n$. If you pick a continuous map $f : S^n \to S^p \times S^q$ with $p+q=n$, there is induced a map in cohomology
$$f^* : \Lambda(x',p)\otimes \Lambda(x'',q) \longrightarrow \Lambda(x,n)$$
by the Künneth formula. If $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the projections to $S^p$ and $S^q$, respectively, this corresponds to the map

$$a\otimes b\longmapsto (\pi_1f)^*(a) \smile (\pi_2f)^*(b).$$

Now what are the degree preserving maps $\Lambda(x',p)\to \Lambda(x,n)$ for $p<n$? Well, simply by degree considerations, there is only the trivial map (since $\Lambda(x,n)$ has nonzero parts only in degree $0$ and $n$) meaning that $\pi_i f$ both induce the trivial map on cohomology, and then so does $f^*$.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but why is $f_\ast = 0$ though? It's probably trivial, but I can't fully understand why, after applying the UCT theorem and obtaining $(f_\ast)^\ast = 0$, this implies $f_\ast = 0$.